# Generate unique ID for each (partial) view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm developing an MVC application, and my clients wants to have a unique ID on each screen. He'll use this ID for as a reference in the manual he's writing.
I'm searching for a generic way, I don't want to hard-code an ID on each separate view/partial.

To make it more complex, partial views are loaded by using jQuery ajax calls, and these partials should also have a unique ID (so in that case the ID of the partial should be displayed, not the ID of the containing page).

Can anyone suggest me a generic strategy to archieve this?
Don't bother about the format of the ID, it can be anything (e.g. a part of a GUID)

Thanks!

Comment: A unique ID on each screen? Couldn't you just use the same ID for each View? As you aren't going to see more than one View at a time. Couldn't you just keep a View - ID dictionary in Session on the server side, and then either check that for existing Unique IDs and serve up a new one? Can you give an example of what you mean by each partial view should have a unique ID and that should show not the containing page ID?

Comment: I'm a little confused here. Do you need to relate these IDs to Clients in any way? If they're just randomly generated, what's the actual use? It sounds to me like any time a client comes to a screen, that Client needs to see the same ID and it needs to be consistent for that View for that Client, is that correct?

Comment: Please specify the main purpose of your MVC app.. May be you could get a full route path for each view which should be unique and then break it up into to character and then to numeric equivalent..

Comment: How are you going to tie the unique values to the documentation?  If you generate it on the fly, what is going to appear in the documentation?  It sounds to me like you need a simple list of name/value pairs that you can put in your documentation and source control.

Comment: What happens if you serve up more than one partial view in a container view? Which partial view id should be the one that is shown?

Answer (score 2):

You could hash the partial view name. That would get you a nice consistent (and unique) name for each view. It would be calculated each time the view was rendered if you put it in your markup.

Something like:

```
@(((RazorView)ViewContext.View).ViewPath.GetHashCode())
```

Should generate you a number based on the name of the View. It's a little dirty & hacky, but I think would serve your purposes.

Apologies. On testing, the above only seems to work for the parent view. I'd have put it in a comment but I don't yet have enough reputation. It might get you on the right track though.

Along similar lines though, you could do similar to the above based upon the filename using:

```
@Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Server.MapPath(VirtualPath)).GetHashCode()
```

Which in my testing does work for an ajax'd partial view

Comment: This won't work for the `ajax calls` which return `partial views.` As then the OP stated the containing view's unique id should be replaced by the partial view.

Comment: Ryan is quite right. I wrote this without testing it, but once I'd plugged it into a sandbox site it didn't quite work.

Comment: @Echo It's a clever idea though.

Comment: Thanks :) Edited to include one that may well work for @Jo. It's possibly even more hacky...

Comment: @Echo The whole question seems kind of hacky, so HACK AWAY good sir. :P